# How to run SQL Server full-text index in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search, ef-core-6.0

I need to run SQL Server full-text index query in EF Core 6.0 as shown here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE CONTAINS(FullTextSearch, '"*glove*" AND "*yellow*" AND "*large*"');
```

After too much searching, I found some topics and solutions like these:

- [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions)
- [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

And finally, I wrote my query like this:

```
var searchCondition = string.Join(" AND ", words.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => $"\"*{x}*\""));
DbContext.Products.Where(s => EF.Functions.Contains(s.FullTextSearch, searchCondition));
```

But the result it's not what I expected, it's the generated query:

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [p].[Id], ... 
FROM [Products] AS [p] 
WHERE FREETEXT([p].[FullTextSearch], @__searchCondition_2)
```

I don't want to use `FreeText` - I need `CONTAINS`.

What do I have to do?

---

**UPDATE:**
Everythings work very well and the problem was checking old version of the code.

Comment: @Charlieface What do you mean that I can't use wildcard prefix, first query works very well in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Linq-to-sql is not Entity Framework. Please pay attention to tag descriptions.

Comment: @GertArnold, You are right, It was a mistake from me in tagging